# Как поменять заголовок письма

Tags: php, wordpress

Вот код отправки письма

```
$headers = array(
    'От: TenderGo <wordpress@gotendergo.ru>',
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'
);

wp_mail($mailTo, $thm, $msg, $headers);
```

Письмо приходит в таком вот виде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поменять жирный "WordPress" на то что мне нужно? На пример на заголовок компании от которой приходит письмо.

Answer (score 0):

Нет такого "От". Правильно писать "From"

```
$headers = array(
    'From: TenderGo <wordpress@gotendergo.ru>',
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'
);

wp_mail($mailTo, $thm, $msg, $headers);
```

Comment: Все равно пишет "WordPRess"